# pydoop installation on python 3.4.3

Tags: python, hadoop, pip, python-3.4

I am trying to install pydoop via following command

```
pip3.4 install pydoop
```

The installation is interrupted with following error

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-jwy57_9u/pydoop/setup.py", line 41
        print 'using setuptools version', setuptools.__version__
                                       ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

I think the error has to do with mismatch in python version as there should be parantheses in call to 'print' in python3.

I am able to install other packages using `pip3.4 install`

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](http://crs4.github.io/pydoop/installation.html) clearly state that Pydoop requires Python 2.7 (or 2.6) as a pre-requisite. As far as I know, there is no current support for Python 3 provided by Pydoop. In short, you need to switch to Python 2.7 (or 2.6).

Answer (score 0):

As sgp mentioned, pydoop is only supported by Python 2. I suggest to preview the slides [here](http://www.slideshare.net/DonaldMiner/hadoop-with-python) and particularly

> [image]

where comparison to Python and Java for Hadoop. Because Hadoop is natively written in Java, the Python community on hadoop is far smaller.

> [image]

where the native implementation in Java outperforms the other ones.

**Other options contain**

1. use Java with Hadoop
2. or other libraries such as Hadoopy, mrjob and dumbo: Hadoopy not mentioning Python version explicitly on its 2-4 years old-dated repos in github, mrjob supports Python 3 as well by [this](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/) and dumbo's websites are down from github [here](https://github.com/klbostee/dumbo).
3. [octopy](https://code.google.com/archive/p/octopy/)

Comment: Is this statement still valid now? Here it says they have tested pydoop on Python 2.7 & 3.6
https://crs4.github.io/pydoop/installation.html#prerequisites